# Serializing simple ASP.Net Object with Byte Array to Bson, C# wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have a simple ASP.Net Object to collect file information for storage in Mongo.  The FileAttrib class is already populated.

```
public class FileAttrib
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileContent { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }   
}
```

I have tried several iterations of serializing this object to Bson with no luck.  It seems simple enough but I am missing something.

```
public async void AddDocumentToMongo(string db, FileAttrib fa)
{
    _client = MongoDbConnection.GetMongoClient();
    _database = MongoDbConnection.GetMongoDatabase(_client, db);
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<FileAttrib>("testInsert");

    var doc = BsonDocument.Create(fa);

    await collection.InsertOneAsync(doc);
}
```

The error is created in the BsonDocumentCreate Statement:{".NET type FileUpload.Models.FileAttrib cannot be mapped to BsonType.Document.\r\nParameter name: value"}

I'm not sure what this means but I think it must be fairly simple to solve - I'm just not getting it right now.

Comment: what version of mongo driver do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Just hat the same error.

Instead of

```
var doc = BsonDocument.Create(fa);
```

use

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
var doc = fa.ToBsonDocument();
```